# useRef.current does not work inside a onLayout callback due to being accessed in useAnimatedStyle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, layout, react-native-reanimated

While trying to make an expandable component where when tapped, it expands to a dynamic height with animation, I ran into this weird behavior where a `useRef` object would not update.

```
const contentHeight = useRef(0)
const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false) 
const eleHeight = useSharedValue(0)

const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
  console.log(contentHeight.current)
  return ({
    height: withSpring(eleHeight.value)
  })})

return <View> 
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setExpand(!expand)}> 
    <Text>{title}</Text>
    <Animated.View 
       style=[animatedStyle] 
       onLayout={getContentHeight}
    > 
      {expand && <Text>unknown content</Text> }
    </Animated.View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Inside `getContentHeight`:

```
const getContentHeight = (event) => {
        const height = event.nativeEvent.layout.height
        console.log('-------onlayout')
        if (contentHeight.current === 0) {
            console.log('CH is zero now', contentHeight.current, height)
            contentHeight.current = height;
            eleHeight.value = height
            console.log('updated to ', contentHeight.current, height)
        }
    };
```

The output is always

```
console: CH is zero now 0 30 
console: updated to 0 30
```

(around 30 because withSpring)

useRef value does not change when I set `contentHeight.current = height` and height is not 0, which is strange.

I also struggled with custom layout animation using `react-native-reanimated` if anyone wanna give me a hand.

***EDIT***: Some major findings and clarifications after hours of debugging...

1. The code I posted is not the full code and does not achieve what I want it to do, but it does allow you to recreate the problem.
2. onLayout gets affected by animatedStyle! I thought it was the other way around initially. During initial rendering, the onLayout gets called with a height of 30. The actual height is 0, but because `eleHeight` starts as 0, the padding and margin are each 15, thus the value is 30. (I didn't include those styling in the code).
3. My use of `contentHeight.current` inside `useAnimatedStyle` is what caused the behavior of it not updating, but I don't know why.

Comment: I did find a solution using LayoutAnimation for what I want to do. https://blog.logrocket.com/building-react-native-collapsible-accordions/#creating-simple-accordion-without-animations
But I remember Layoutanimation is not very performant and thats why I wanted to use ```react-native-reanimated```.

Comment: After hours of debugging... The entire reason that ```contentHeight.current``` did not update is just becase the ```console.log(contentHeight.current)``` inside ```animatedStyles``` !!!! WHAT!!

I still don't really understand why tho, I would appreciate it if someone can explain. (Something to do with reference and how it is accessed at a different thread??)

Comment: https://www.reanimated2.com/docs/layout-animations/layout-transitions

It only took me 10 hours to find this. Not too bad :D